# How to block all fields, and unlock select ones for an HTML datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I want to block almost all check boxes, I want only 2 and 4 days of the week to be available. Does anyone know how to do this?

Currently have this code:

```
<input class="unstyled" type="date" id="datapicker">

const date = new Date();
currentDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
document.getElementById('datapicker').value = currentDate;
document.getElementById('datapicker').min = currentDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about this issue: [Date picker in HTML5](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/). Take a look at the section "Can’t eliminate days, but here’s a suggested workaround". You can't restrict specific days using only markup, but the author suggests below workaround:

```
var date = document.querySelector('[type=date]');

function noMondays(e){
  var day = new Date( e.target.value ).getUTCDay();

  // Days in JS range from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday
  if( day == 1 ){
    e.target.setCustomValidity('OH NOES! We hate Mondays! Please pick any day but Monday.');
  } else {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
date.addEventListener('input',noMondays);
```

There is also *step* argument, but it only let you limit partucular gap between days (e.g. every second day):

```
<input class="unstyled" type="date" id="datapicker" step="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will help you,

```
$(function() {
      $("#datapicker").datepicker(
        { beforeShowDay: function(day) {
            var day = day.getDay();
            if (day == 2 || day == 4) {
                return [true];
            } else {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        });
    });
```